# How to get value from docker-credential-osxkeychain

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

How do you get credentials

Docker [describe](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/) it as getting it from config.json but it is in "credsStore" and how do you get it out from there?

```
 cat ~/.docker/config.json
{
    "auths": {
        "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {}
    },
    "credsStore": "desktop",
    "experimental": "enabled",
    "stackOrchestrator": "swarm"
}
```

Using `docker-credential-osxkeychain get <??>`

It is like no matter what I try to "get" is comes back with:

```
docker-credential-osxkeychain <store|get|erase|list|version>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short answer**

the command `docker-credentials-osxkeychain get` reads from standard input and expects server url as described [here](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers/client#Get)
so one can do something like

```
$ echo "https://index.docker.io/v1/" | docker-credential-osxkeychain get
```

You can find the server url using `docker-credential-osxkeychain list`

```
$ docker-credential-osxkeychain list
{"https://index.docker.io/v1/":"someuser"}
```

---

**Long answer**

First, you might want to change `credsStore` to `osxkeychain` which makes `~/.docker/config.json` look like

```
{
  "stackOrchestrator" : "swarm",
  "credsStore" : "osxkeychain",
  "auths" : {

  },
  "experimental" : "disabled"
}
```

Second, login with docker cli using `docker login`

```
$ docker login
Login with your Docker ID to push and pull images from Docker Hub. If you don't have a Docker ID, head over to https://hub.docker.com to create one.
Username: someuser
Password:
Login Succeeded
```

On successful login, `docker-credential-osxkeychain` has stored the username and password in osxkeychain which can be retrieved using `docker-credential-osxkeychain get`

```
$ docker-credential-osxkeychain list
{"https://index.docker.io/v1/":"someuser"}
```

we can use the url as the key to get our credentials
note: docker-credential-osxkeychain get uses stdin to read the input.

```
$ echo "https://index.docker.io/v1/" | docker-credential-osxkeychain get
{"ServerURL":"https://index.docker.io/v1/","Username":"someuser","Secret":"your-actual-password"}
```